# How to have a product with different price options

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I want all my product to have multiple prices.
for example:
I'm selling windows. every window has a normal type, ultra thin type and a strong type.
some windows doesn't have a strong type, 
every type has its own price.
The user can select the type from a dropbox.
Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used ubercart's product attributes. I made a list that the buyer must select from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an easy way, use the drupal commerce module.
http://drupal.org/project/commerce